# Import/Export based on conditions

Tags: python

Imagine a `settings.py`:

```
if condition:
  A_SETTING = True
else:
  A_SETTING = False
```

how can I have another file just import it and get the setting based on the condition:

```
import settings

use_setting_somehow(settings.A_SETTING)
```

**UPDATE:** Ignore this please. I had a mistake in my function.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Doh, has been a long day. Maybe time to stop coding for today. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving a value that depends on a particular condition should probably be a getter in stead of just a settings variable.

```
def get_setting(setting):
    if condition:
        return 1
    else:
        return 'A'

import settings
settings.get_setting('BLARP')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**settings.py**:

```
if 1 == 1:
    TESTVAR = True
else:
    # Note that you need a else, because if your
    # logic fails in the statements above, you'll have no variable..
    TESTVAR = False
```

in **test.py**:

```
import settings
print settings.TESTVAR
```

Comment: Oddly enough I was partially wrong, if statements does not create a local object, it's global per default. Nice :)